# How to remove duplicate points in scatterplot in R?

Tags: duplicates, scatter-plot

I have data from an experiment, where participants have been working in pairs, and they have to rate their enjoyment after the task. Each player is always assigned a position in the task (position 1 or 2).

I am trying to plot each pair in a scatterplot, so that I get the enjoyment-rating from position 1 on the x-axis and the enjoyment rating from position 2 on the Y-axis. Hence, in my scatter plot one pair should be represented by a single point in the plot, with the coordinates: (Enjoyment_position_1; Enjoyment_position 2).

Now, I am having the problem that my scatterplot produces **duplicates** of every value.

```
library(gdata)
library(ggplot2)
Participant<-(c(1:20))  
Pair<-(c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10))  
Position<-(c(1:2))  
Enjoyment<-(c(2,6,8,4,5,6,2,3,9,8,6,5,3,2,6,6,6,7,8,8))  
Data<-data.frame(Participant, Pair, Position, Enjoyment)

Scatter_Controlled_1B<-ggplot(Data, aes(Enjoyment[Position==1], Enjoyment[Position==2]))
Scatter_Controlled_1B + geom_point(shape=1, position=position_jitter(width=0.1, height=0.1))
```

How do I remove the duplicates?